# Искажение изображения при появлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, background

Указал в коде

```
   android:background="@drawable/Фон"
```

все работает нормально пока нету клавиатуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после активации клавиатуры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собственно как это лечить ???

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть весь код разметки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `AndroidManifest.xml` пропишите

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

**adjustResize** - размеры компонентов в окне активити могут изменяться, чтобы освободить место для экранной клавиатуры.

**adjustPan** - окно активити и его компоненты не изменяются, а сдвигаются таким образом, чтобы текстовое поле с фокусом не было закрыто клавиатурой.

**adjustUnspecified** - настройка по умолчанию. Система сама выбирает нужный режим.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста в чем заключаются функции этой строки

Comment: Спасибо за верный ответ